# Database view support in Ignite 2,1?

Tags: ignite, gridgain

Does Ignite 2.1 support creation of database views? I see we have table, index creation, etc. I think H2 does support it. I ask because we have plenty right now & want to see if i can do the below,

1. Make Ignite as a JDBC data source (like any other database Postgresql, Oracle, etc)
2. Allow ORM tools like Hibernate or MyBatis to connect to Ignite & then be able to leverage their ORM capabilities.

Currently it looks like item 1 is possible (with limitations which is fine with me)...but item 2 is not..is my understanding true?

I have other cumbersome ways in mind of working around this (like by using continuous query or other event based cache updates, etc)...but being able to support views will make it easier to introduce ignite in our environment without writing a lot of boiler plate code).

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignite doesn't support creating views right now, but here's a ticket for that: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-5951

1. Is possible to use Ignite as Datasource. You can connect to Ignite with its [JDBC Driver](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jdbc-driver)
2. It's possible to use Ignite with Hibernate, See the [documentation for it](https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/hibernate-l2-cache)